# Generating BSP tree from raw data

Tags: c++, bsp-tree

I know how to utilize a prebuilt BSP tree with old 3d levels like Quake and so and have even written a level renderer. Now, I am moving onto the next step which is actually building that BSP tree myself. I know the process behind it but I was wondering if anyone had any advice or a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 8):

A site to consult: [BSP Trees: Theory and Implementation](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/bsp-trees/). Found from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) links section, of course.

*edit* I'm sorry, the article has been deleted from devmaster.net, but of the same author (Samuel Ranta-Eskola) [here](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/bsptree/bsp.pdf) is a link to a PDF.

Comment: Found it on wayback: http://web.archive.org/web/20111115163809/http://www.devmaster.net/articles/bsp-trees